# Bridge between physical interface and virtual (Cockpit)

Tags: networking, dhcp, network-bridge, cockpit

At the moment I'm using Debian 11 as the main system and Ubuntu 18.04 as the system for virtualization, I do all the management through Cockpit.

The server is connected via a router, the connection to the router is via DHCP.

Currently I'm assigning an address IP for the virtual machine like this:

[image: screen cockpit settings]
direct -> eno1 - router network from the physical port.

network -> default - network for virtual machines.

How can I get only 192.168.3.250 instead of 192.168.3.47 (the address received via DHCP through the "eno1" interface, i.e. virtual machine -> physical port bridge)?